# Повторное использование кода и проблема множественного наследования в C#

Tags: c#

Существует следующая структура приложения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Реализация метода **Id** из интерфейса **IGetId** **одинаковая везде**. Но, исходя из этой структуры его нужно будет каждый раз переписывать в каждом классе, имплементирующего интерфейсы, порожденные от **IGetId**.

Если бы не было **BaseModel** это в принципе не было бы проблемой, т.к. можно было бы вынести реализацию этого метода в какой нибудь абстрактный класс *AGetId* и от него наследоваться, но множественное наследование не поддерживается, а композиция в данном случае нарушает целостность.

В PHP существует очень удобный инструмент - [Trait](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.traits.php). Он отлично решает данную проблему, но, к сожалению, в C# такого функционала нету.

В C# есть нечто похожее - [extension methods](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods), хоть это и совершенно разные вещи. Я пробовал сделать что-то с использованием методов расширения, но получилось на мой взгляд "не очень":

**IGetId**:

```
public interface IGetId
{
    int Id { get; }
}
```

**Extension methods**:

```
public static class CoreExtensions
{       
    public static int Id(this IGetId obj)
    {
        return obj.Id;
    }
}
```

В любом случае, это не дало ожидаемого результата, мне по прежнем нужно реализовывать **Id** в каждом классе.

Существуют ли какие-то средства для решения данной проблемы?

Comment: В BaseModel нельзя поместить Id ваш? Да и вообще зачем нужен интерфейс IGetId, как вы его используете?

Comment: А почему бы не ввести промежуточный класс BaseModelWithId?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я бы предложил такую иерархию наследования:

```
// библиотечные интерфейсы
interface IGetId { int Id { get; } }
interface IPerson : IGetId { string Name { get; } }
interface IAddres : IGetId { string City { get; } }

// универсальный базовый класс
class BaseModel { /* ... */ }

// вспомогательный класс
abstract class BaseModelWithId : BaseModel, IGetId
{
    int id;
    public int Id => id;
}

// реальные классы
class Person : BaseModelWithId, IPerson
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Необходимость реализовывать `IGetId` в `Person` отпала.

---

Хотя в общем случае вы правы, trait'ов не хватает. Есть хорошие шансы, что они появятся в будущем C# 8.

Comment: А не нарушает ли пустой BaseObject YAGNI?

Comment: @АртёмОконечников: Судя по всему, он у ТС не пустой.

Comment: @VladD, а почему id сразу в BaseObject не положить? ну и соответственно реализовать в нем GetId

Comment: @Grundy: Если бы он там уже лежал, у ТС не было бы проблемы. (У меня опечатка, там `BaseModel`.) Класс `BaseModel`, судя по всему, дан сверху (ну или не все его потомки должны иметь `Id`).

Comment: Этот вариант действительно решает проблему, спасибо ;)
И да, не все потомки BaseModel должны возвращать Id

Comment: @Ep1demic: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло.

Answer (score 4):

Замените наследование композицией:

```
class Id
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public Id(int value) => Value = value;

    public override bool Equals(object obj) => ((obj is Id id) && Value.Equals(id.Value))
                                            || ((obj is int i) && Value.Equals(i));
    public override int GetHashCode() => Value.GetHashCode();

    public static implicit operator int(Id id) => id.Value;
    public static implicit operator Id(int i) => new Id(i);
}
```

Ну, действительно, классы же ваши включают в себя Id.

Используем:

```
interface IPerson
{
    string Name { get; }
}

class Person : IPerson
{
    public Id Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Вместо интерфейса `IGetId` теперь вы везде используете класс `Id` и его свойство `Value`.

Comment: Да, это рабочий вариант, но как по мне - не самый красивый.

Comment: @Ep1demic, ваше право выбрать тот вариант, который вам больше всего подойдет или больше всего понравится :)

Answer (score 1):

Для соблюдения плюрализма мнений, добавлю вариант с идентификатором в базовом классе:

```
interface IGetId { int Id { get; } }
interface IPerson : IGetId { string Name { get; } }
interface IAddres : IGetId { string City { get; } }
```

Базовый класс:

```
class BaseModel : IGetId { 
    public virtual int Id { get { /* ... */ } }
}
```

Конкретный

```
class PersonModel : BaseModel, IPerson
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

(Я бы переименовал интерфейс `IGetId` во что-то на подобии `IМодельСИдентификатором` и, как следствие базовую модель)

Answer (score 0):

С помощью методов расширения действительно можно решить вашу проблему.

Делается это следующим образом. Из интерфейса убираем свойство `Id`. Остаётся просто:

```
public interface IGetId
{
}
```

В методе расширения пишем код получения `Id`:

```
public static class CoreExtensions
{
    public static int Id(this IGetId obj)
    {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

Можно использовать:

```
var person = new Person();
Console.WriteLine(person.Id()); // вызывается extension method

IGetId g = person;
Console.WriteLine(g.Id()); // аналогично
```

Comment: Все это хорошо, но мне нужно возвращать Id из объекта IGetId и если убрать из интерфейса свойство работать этот код не будет, а если оставить - будет выше описанная проблема ;)

Comment: @Ep1demic - Вместо свойства - метод. И всё работает.

Comment: как мне кажется, метод не решит эту проблему - он попросту не сможет достучаться к этому свойству...

Comment: @Ep1demic - так не нужно свойство. Полностью его убираем. Вместо него теперь метод.

Comment: Хорошо, а Id мне как возвращать?) откуда его брать?)

Comment: @Ep1demic - в вопросе вы писали: "_Реализация метода Id из интерфейса IGetId одинаковая везде._" Вот эту реализацию и вставьте в этот метод расширения. Подозреваю, что на самом деле там используются другие свойства объектов. Это значит, что реализация вовсе не одинаковая и её действительно нужно писать в каждом классе отдельно.